Forgotten Title "Reincarnated as Villain Extra"
I think this is a korean novel. If not, then i think it's something from webnovel/royalroad. It could be a japanese novel too, I'm not sure. But the chance is rather low. It is definitely not a Chinese work, that's for sure.
The protagonist gets reincarnated into some video game / novel, but as an extra villain role, not the protagonist. If i recall correctly, his fiancée declared their marriage nullification seconds after our mc has arrived in that world (or the other way around), and joined the world's main character harem shortly afterword.
(Not confirmed) The protagonist is obese at the start, but slimmed down shortly afterward.
According to the unmodified history of the video game or novel, the fiancée was able to fit in with the video game/novel main character's harem without issues. However, the protagonist of the series changed it. The former fiancée was unable to forget about him, she even tried to stalk him using some kind of power through birds... even though their relationship is long over. She felt something was wrong after seeing him with a new girl.
The main character of the game/novel has a childhood friend, and according to the history of the original game/novel, she was also in his harem. However, due to the butterfly effects the protagonist generated, this childhood friend felt that the main character was paying less attention to her, and after some misunderstanding and multiple coincidences, she fell in love with the protagonist. In a dancing ball party, she even treated the main character like a stranger after seeing him taking other women's side instead of hers. For some reason, I do remember both the main character and protagonist hate each other. This part, i think it exists around chapter 78.

found it, the answer is
How To Live As An Academy Extra Villain
the chapter count is shorter than i thought

:) Flesh out your answer such that it shows why this answers your question, just like if you were answering someone else. And don't forget to self accept when you can.

The dancing ball party is chapter 76.
As for the Fiancée part, it slowly changes overtime

:-D [edit] the details in.
